# Set clim for geoplot axes subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using geoplot which uses matplotlib to create plots.

One such functionality is `geoplot.pointplot`, that creates an `AxesSubplot` every time you call it. This allows you to call it multiple times and overlay a bunch of `pointplot`s. The underlying code simply creates a matplotlib `scatter`.

My problem is that for each of these `pointplot`s, `geoplot` assigns them an individually unique `cmap`, and so if one plot is yellow at a value of `40`, another might be blue. This is an issue, as I don't want to have multiple legends for 1 plot. Ideally, all the plots follow a single legend and the values are consistent among the plots.

Below is an example:

[image]

Any help in solving this would be much appreciated. I tried feeding `vmin` and `vmax` to `geoplot.pointplot` but they each had no affect.

EDIT:

I have found a "solution". By adding a point to each subplot at the south pole, it falls outside the bounds of the graph and as such artificially increases the range of the colorbar. I'm not answering with this, because this is a vry hacky way of getting what I want done, and not ideal. This is done through the following code:

```
t = t.append({'altitude': max_alt, 'geometry': Point(0, -90)}
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the approach in my answer?

Comment: @WilliamMiller Just tried it, it worked well, thankyou

Comment: Glad to hear it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'proper' way to do this is by creating a `matplotlib.cm.cmap` instance along with a `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` and passing them in to `geoplot.pointplot` via keyword arguments `cmap` and `norm` respectively. The colormap being used by the image in the question is `viridis`, here is an example of creating and normalizing a `viridis` `cmap`:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors, cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis')
norm = colors.Normalize(min(x), max(x))
```

This will normalize the colormap to the scale of `x`, you would then pass these objects into each call of `geoplot.pointplot`,

```py
geoplot.pointplot(..., cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
geoplot.pointplot(..., cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
# etc...
```

This will give you the same colorbar across all plots.